# How to add line breaks inside Gallery Captions

Tags: captions, line-breaks

I am using this excellent piece of code to insert a line break in single image captions by way of inserting a pipe character...

Now I would like your help to try to incorporate this into the gallery image captions too.

Here's the original code that works for single image captions.  My attempt at the gallery code is below.

```
/*
*********************************************
Function to allow multi-line photo captions.
This function will split captions onto multiple lines if it detects
a "|" (pipe) symbol.
**********************************************
*/
/* Override existing caption shortcode handlers with our own */
add_shortcode('wp_caption', 'multiline_caption');
add_shortcode('caption', 'multiline_caption');

/* Our new function */
function multiline_caption($attr, $content = null) {
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
'id' => '',
'align' => 'alignnone',
'width' => '',
'caption' => ''
), $attr));

if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
return $content;

if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

$new_caption = str_replace("|", "<br />", $caption);

return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $new_caption . '</p></div>';    }
```

Original code by Mark Wood: http://digitalnotions.net/multi-line-captions-in-wordpress

**Here is my attempt with the gallery shortcode in functions.php file**

This is basically the code copied from wp-includes/media.php gallery function.

I've amended the output function at the end of this code (original code commented) to try to get the pipe in there, but it's not working on my gallery captions !

Your help greatly appreciated.

```
remove_shortcode('gallery', 'gallery_shortcode');

add_shortcode('gallery', 'multiline_caption_gallery');


/* Our new function */

function multiline_caption_gallery($attr) {
global $post;

static $instance = 0;
$instance++;

extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'order'      => 'ASC',
    'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
    'id'         => $post->ID,
    'itemtag'    => 'dl',
    'icontag'    => 'dt',
    'captiontag' => 'dd',
    'columns'    => 3,
    'size'       => 'thumbnail',
    'include'    => '',
    'exclude'    => ''
), $attr));

$id = intval($id);
if ( 'RAND' == $order )
    $orderby = 'none';

if ( !empty($include) ) {
    $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
    $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

    $attachments = array();
    foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
        $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
    }
} elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
    $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
} else {
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
}

if ( empty($attachments) )
    return '';

if ( is_feed() ) {
    $output = "\n";
    foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
        $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
    return $output;
}

$itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
$captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
$columns = intval($columns);
$itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
$float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

$selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

$gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
    $gallery_style = "
    <style type='text/css'>
        #{$selector} {
            margin: auto;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-item {
            float: {$float};
            margin-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            width: {$itemwidth}%;
        }
        #{$selector} img {
            border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
        }
        #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
            margin-left: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
$size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
$gallery_div = "<div id='$selector' class='gallery galleryid-{$id} gallery-columns-{$columns} gallery-size-{$size_class}'>";
$output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

$i = 0;



foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
    $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

    $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='gallery-item'>";
    $output .= "
        <{$icontag} class='gallery-icon'>
            $link
        </{$icontag}>";





/* ORIGINAL CODE DISABLED


        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {

$output .= "
            <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
            " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
            </{$captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}

$output .= "
        <br style='clear: both;' />
    </div>\n";

return $output;}


 */   // end disable original code




// REPLACEMENT CODE added by sol to allow line breaks in the captions

        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
 $new_captiontag = str_replace("|", "<br />", $captiontag);     

        $output .= "
            <{$new_captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
            " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
            </{$new_captiontag}>";
    }
    $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
    if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
        $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
}

$output .= "
        <br style='clear: both;' />
    </div>\n";

return $output;}
```

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, this has been fixed in 3.4: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18311

Answer (score 0):

You can css it using width no?

just do a css condition for that p tag (wp-caption-text)
say the default width is 100 px you can do it 50 px...
Sinple solution but should work good.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the whole point of the pipe character "|" is to allow the insertion of a line break arbitrarily between specific words etc